# Would it be wrong to say: "I am wrong!"?

Tags: word-choice

Should I say: "I am wrong!" or "I am mistaken!"?

I, as a person, am not wrong for sure! What I did/tell/do could be 'wrong'! Please, explain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're mixing two different and perfectly fine meanings of the same word.

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wrong)

> **wrong** adjective (NOT CORRECT)
>
> A2 If **someone is wrong**, they are not correct in their judgment or
>   statement about something.
>  
>   *You were wrong about the time - the bank closed at 3.30. 
> He's wrong in
>   thinking that we will support the project financially.*
>
> **wrong** adjective (NOT WORKING) ​
>  
> B1 [ after verb ] not working
>   correctly 
> *Something's wrong with the television - the picture's fuzzy.
>
>   The doctors are still trying to find out what's wrong.*

You as a human being may be perfectly healthy ["working" fine - NOT B1] but still you may **be wrong** [not correct - A2] in some of your judgements or beliefs.

> [**mistaken**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mistaken?q=MISTAKEN) adjective
>   C1 **wrong** in what you believe, or based on a belief that is wrong

*I was mistaken* and *I was wrong* are synonymous if you want to express that your judgment was not correct. As pointed by @Smock, you can say either.

Comment: I may be wrong but ... are they not quite synonymous? Both Cambridge and Oxford Dictionaries mark them as synonyms https://www.lexico.com/en/synonym/mistaken Do you have any source to back up the difference that you have pointed? I think that wrong is the opposite of correct and can be used when something is morally wrong or when something is factually wrong.

Comment: @jonathanjo Ok, I see, I think that the difference it's too subtle, as you have pointed. You should compile your comments in an answer. No irony.

Comment: Good suggestion.  Please do comment on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in error, you can certainly say either.

They are not synonyms: **I am wrong** includes more kinds of error than **I am mistaken**.

- **mistaken** is only for matters of fact, perception, logic etc
- **wrong** can be used for those kinds of errors, but also for use with values and other moral positions: any kind of error.

Some examples:

- **You are wrong in punishing him, it didn't matter** (moral error)
- **You are mistaken in punishing him, he is innocent** (factual error)
- **He is wrong to charge £100** (could be any reason, including greed, typing wrong numbers, anything)
- **He is mistaken to charge £100** (could only be errors of fact, typing wrong numbers etc)
- **I am the wrong man, officer, you should find the real killer** (Police looking for killer, but I am not him.  Very common theme in [Hitchcock films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Hitchcock).)

OED has dozens of entries for **wrong** including:

- "Of persons: deviating from integrity, rectitude, or probity; doing or prone to do that which is evil, noxious, or unjust; opprobrious, vicious."
- "Not in consonance with facts or truth; incorrect, false, mistaken."

It is wider than **mistaken** which has only three non-obsolete entries:

- "Wrongly conceived, entertained, or carried out; erroneous."
- "Of a person or persons: having a wrong opinion or judgement; labouring under a misapprehension."
- "Of a person's identity: with regard to which a mistake is or has been made."

Just to be clear: these can be considered subtle differences.  (For those interested, the philosopher JL Austin covered these kinds of issues in his book *How to do things with words*, 1955, easily found online.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not *sure* you are wrong, and you just want to say that you realize you *might* be wrong, you can say any of these:

> - I could be wrong.
> - Maybe I'm wrong.
> - I'm just guessing.
> - Don't quote me on that.

Your sentences...

> - I am wrong.
> - I am mistaken.

... are grammatical and idiomatic, but they mean you think you definitely *are* wrong. You could also say:

> - I stand corrected.
> - My mistake.
> - My bad.